# How to compress video without losing video quality in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a social media app where the users can upload their videos and watch them in the app. But it takes lots of time to retrieve videos from firebase due to its large size (like 13 seconds video size is 5mb). So I thought to compress video size but after compressing the size ,the video quality gets low. How can I compress video without losing its quality?

```
mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView)
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,-1)
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_BRIGHTNESS,1);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

Comment: In other to compress without losing any quality you need to use some [lossless compression codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Lossless_video_compression), google for android libraries with lossless video compression and pick what seems best to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some great lib's on github

Some of the video compressor are

[LightCompressor](https://github.com/AbedElazizShe/LightCompressor)  and   [VideoCompressor](https://github.com/fishwjy/VideoCompressor)

Hope these will help u.

Comment: Actually I have already visited this github sites but I can't understand anything. Can u plz make  me understand using my own code.